# My scss doesnt work

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display a table and make it pretty with scss bu I ran into a problem. I have no errors, my page loads but it is like i don't have a scss.
I am new to ruby on rails so I have no idea why it is not working ;/ i am getting no errors. Can someone tell me where I am making the mistake?

my controler file:

```
class KurseviController < ApplicationController
  def indeks
    @people= { "Makra" => "15", "Backe" => "17" , "Napster" => "20" }
  end
end
```

my indeks.html file

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Ime</th>
    <th>Broj</th>

</tr> 
<% @people.each do |key, value| %>
<tr class=<%= cycle('even','odd')%>>
    <td> <%= key%> </td>
    <td> <%= value %> </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

my scss file :

```
table {
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }

td{
    padding: 50px;
}

.even {
    background-color: #D6E1C3
}
```

My applicaion.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MyFirstApp</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your scss file `application.scss`?  Are you including it in application stylesheet if not?

Comment: Well that's basic CSS not *actual* SCSS. :)  But not actually related to the issue I suspect.

Comment: can you paste your application.css file code?

Comment: In my application.css i have imported the css that i have writed above.
@import 'kursevi.scss';

Comment: What is the order in your `application.css` or `application.scss`? It might have gotten overridden by some other `css`. Inspect the element via Chrome console and see if the `css` class from `kursevi.css` is crossed out or not. I suggest you post the `application.css` for us to have a look.